# How to mock AWS S3.getobject() using mocha?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-s3, mocha.js, aws-lambda

During tests using mocha, i'm having invocation issue with S3.getObject().

My code in Lambda is like this:

**index.js:** (Inside AWS Lambda function)

```
S3.getObject(s3FileParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        var message = "Error while trying to get file object " + fullFileName + " from bucket " + bucketName + ". Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function. Error: " + err;
        console.error(message);
    }
    else {
        userMetaDataJson = data.Metadata;
    }
    resolve();
})
```

And in the test file 
**index.test.js** (using mocha)

```
AWSMock.mock('S3', 'getObject', function (params, callback){
    var metaDataParams = {
        "Metadata": {
            "startDate": "2016-11-11 12:34:56:000",
            "endDate":   "2016-11-11 12:34:56:000",
            "userName":  "userName",
            "originalFileName": "originalFileName"
        }
    };
    callback(false, metaDataParams);
});
```

When running this test with mocha, there is no call to the mocked getObject() and it's calling to the original one, is there anything that I can do ?

Is there any other approach I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create the S3 instance inside my AWS Lambda and not as global variable

Comment: That might solve the mocking issue, but it is discouraged for performance, as S3 will be instantiated upon every invocation of the function, instead of when creating the container.

Answer (score 0):

One hint: instead of mocking individual S3 responses, you could also take advantage of some very sophisticated existing mocking frameworks. For instance [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) provides functionality that is very similar to the actual S3 API.

You could also take a look at [LocalStack](https://github.com/spulec/moto), a framework which combines existing tools and provides a fully functional local cloud environment (including S3) that can be used for integration testing.

Although some of these tools are written in other languages (Python), it should be easy to spin up the test environment in an external process from your node.js tests.